# How to edit plugin's html?

Tags: plugins, customization, html

Hello Dear Wordpress Developers,

I'm using [Awesome Sticky Header by DevCanyon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-sticky-header/) plugin on my website. I want to edit this plugin's html. Because with plugin's settings only thing that I can add is menu's. I want to add custom html. like search bar or something.

ps: English is not my native language. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the option to edit any plugin's code from the plugins screen. Under the name of each plugin you should see an Edit link which gives you access to the plugin code.  Any changes that you make to the plugin will be completely wiped out when the plugin updates unless you ensure that you disable updates.

Comment: i know that, but there's only .php files in the plugin. I couldn't find the HTML part. Is it possible to check the Awesome Sticky Header by DevCanyon, then tell me where is?