# how can I edit the HTML of yith ajax product filter

Tags: plugins, categories, filters, ajax, html

this question is basically the same as [How to edit plugin's html?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209239/how-to-edit-plugins-html) but they also did not get an answer to their question. I am using Yith AJAX Product Filter Premium Plugin and I am in contact with their support but they haven't replied quickly enough and I need an answer to my questions. So I need to add a class to certain elements in the HTML of the plugin but I cannot for the life of me locate the HTML file. I know there is output from all the different files into an HTML file but I cannot find it. The developer said this and provided me a screenshot showing the HTML file so I know it exists:

Hi there,

thanks for contact us!
I look your css and I understand that you need a specific class to add the correct style and prevent to lost it after a filter selection, right ?
My idea is to add a CSS class to tag , look here:

http://prntscr.com/pvtwj3

In the a tag I can add via code the product category slug, in this way you can create some specific rules or...if your have another idea feel free to tell me about that.

so I got a plugin that searches all the strings of the plugin files and my unique words that would be in the HTML like the a href src's I'm using and such were not found. I also tried editing the slug in the category specifications like the developer said but I'm new to wordpress and it did nothing, just broke the page so I had to revert it back to the original slug. 
The problem here is that this page's HTML is not editable because it is basically just categories and products, which are filtered by the plugin. I originally identified an element by its href tag and applied style but if a product is filtered, the href src changes. So I need to add a class to the element in the HTML and apply just 1 style to that that will be valid across all pages. Hope this is clear, feel free to ask for clarification.

editing question for @Kaperto Like in the picture I posted from the developer http://prntscr.com/pvtwj3 on the left is a screenshot I sent them which outlines what I want to do. We have the premium version and I still don't find a place to edit the HTML template WITH my elements and input inside it, or even one without it. I need to add a "title" class to the bold element in the screenshot so I can apply the style to just those elements that have that. There are several pages with one title element and they are all list items and have the same classes from the plugin as a default so I can't select just one. I did accomplish selecting just one element by its' href value. However, this value changes upon flitering and the css is no longer valid because the element doesn't match. There are zillions of combinations for filtering, I can't account for them all.

Comment: I test the free version of AJAX Product Filter and I don't find a way to easily add a CSS class to the `a` element. its always possible to edit directly the file of the plugin but then you will no more update this plugin. which CSS class do you want to add ? edit your question to add an example.

Comment: @Kaperto question edited

Comment: I don't understant what represent this element "Aandrijving". it's a product category ? I don't found how to configure the plugin to display that.

Comment: @Kaperto yes it's a category. Sorry, we are going to go with another plugin because this is unworkable... Thank you for your help though. There seems to be no way to access the HTML.